# @AroundInvoke does not work when attribute supplied

Tags: java, annotations

I have following classes.

```
@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD })
public @interface MyLogger {
    public boolean skipParams() default true;
}


    @MyLogger
    @Interceptor
    public class MyInterceptor {
        @AroundInvoke
        public Object logMethod(InvocationContext joinPoint) throws Exception {
    // Some log statements here
        }
    }

    public class MyClass {

      @MyLogger()
      void test1(){
      // some code
       }

    @MyLogger(skipParams = true)
      void test2(){
      // some code
       }

    @MyLogger(skipParams = false)
      void test3(){
      // some code
       }

    }
```

@AroundInvoke does not work when attribute supplied.
logMethod() gets called for test1(), but not for test2() and test3().